# How secure is 'Enable secure LDAP access over the internet' and can access be limited?

Tags: active-directory, azure

We use Azure AD Domain Services and want to use it to authenticate to our local WiFi. For that we want to know, how secure the option "Enable secure LDAP access over the internet" is.

The article [Configure Secure LDAP (LDAPS) for an Azure AD Domain Services managed domain](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/active-directory-ds-admin-guide-configure-secure-ldap) is interesting but also does not state anything about securing the LDAPS access or somehow limit it.

Because it seems not possible to define source-ip-addresses, we guess that after enabling it, Azure AD is really public accessible, is that true?

Which options are there to limit the access?

What is the recommended way to do that?

Comment: This is not an answer to the question per-se, but are you sure you want your authentication for your local WiFi to be reliant not only on the 3rd party service of Azure but also on your internet connection being online? If you have an internet outage, nobody new will be able to connect to your WiFi.

Comment: Based on my knowledge, it is not possible. You could check this [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/8816272-authenticating-wireless-access-points-radius-thr).

Comment: Azure AD DS could manage your VMs on Azure, I don't think it could manage your local device.